# Random number that shows only odd betweet 1-99, shows 20 number in 5 sentences

Tags: java, arrays

I need help with this question. I'm trying to make the program shows odd random number between 1-99 in 5 sentences with 20 values in each sentence. This is what I came up with, it only showed one value in each sentence. Please help me with the rest. Thank you

```
  int[] n = new int[20]; 
  int i = 1;
  while (i<=5)
   {
       int x=(int) (Math.random()*100);
       x=x*2+1;
       while (x<=100)
       {    
           for (int index = 0; index < n.length; index++) 
               {
                    n[index] = (int) (Math.random()*100); 
               }
           for (int index = 0; index < n.length; index++)
               {
                   System.out.print(x + " ");           
               }
           System.out.printf();
           i++;
           break;
       }
 }
```

Comment: Please include input, current output and desired output.

Answer (score 0):

The OP's code stated that it needed odd numbers, and needed to "show", which I take to mean just dumping the output. It is hoped this answer provides guidance, and is not merely copy/pasted as the solution to a homework problem.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int[] odds = new int[100];

    Random rnd = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < odds.length; ++i) {
        int nxt = 0;
        while ( (nxt % 2) == 0) {
            nxt = rnd.nextInt(99) + 1;
        }
        odds[i] = nxt;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < odds.length; ++i) {
        System.out.print(String.format("%2d ", odds[i]));

        if ((i + 1) % 20 == 0) {
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Sample output:

> `73 15 71 15 21 23 63 97 11 11 89 39 75 33 73 53 31 25 43 47`
>   `69 87 85 93 39 59 41 19 67 77 55 53 19 29 49 23 93 63 73 41`
>   `71 27 15 31 39 99 47 43 85 67 81 75 15 37 55 33 97 73 45 47`
>   `37 73 93 89 35 31 29 59 35 61 71 79 15 45 49 11 27 73 23 21`
>   `13 71  7 93 31  9 29 77 21 95 91 63 21 83 43 49 61 63 61  1`

Answer (score 0):

update your code with following:

```
int[] n = new int[20]; 
  int i = 1;
  while (i<=5)
   {
    int x=(int) (Math.random()*100);
    x=x*2+1;
    while (x<=100)
    {   
      for (int index = 0; index < n.length; index++) 
      {
        n[index] = (int) (Math.random()*100); 
      }
      for (int index = 0; index < n.length; index++)
      {
          int x1=(int) (Math.random()*100);
        x1=x1*2+1;
        System.out.print(x1 + " ");          
      }
     System.out.printf("\n");
      i++;
        break;
  }


}
```

Comment: Does this answer keep the values between `1-99` (presumably inclusive)? I do not believe so.

Comment: my answer much concerned about "it only showed one value in each sentence".

Answer (score 0):

Your code is broken exactly here:

```
 for (int index = 0; index < n.length; index++){
       System.out.print(x + " ");           
 }
```

you are printing 20 times the value x that is what you calculated in the up at the beginning

---

I would do something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] n = new int[20];
    int i = 1;
    while (i <= 5) {
        for (int index = 0; index < n.length; index++) {
            // random number between 0-49 then multiplied by 2 +1 still be
            // between 0 and 1-100
            n[index] = (int) (new Random().nextInt(49) * 2 + 1);
        }
        // pretty easy way to print arrays, no loop needed.
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(n));
        i++;
    }
}
```